# Missing more blocks than normal (Fitness/Mempool issue)

Tags: baking, mempool, block, fitness

I've been told this could be a connectivity issue, but I highly doubt that's the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is not your random block missed issue. I miss about 1/3-1/4 blocks I get priority 0 for.

[This](https://gyazo.com/d466979e6a497c91eb8861fb7fb86115) is how my node looks with the current config I have running.

This what what my config looks like:

```
{ "p2p":
   { "bootstrap-peers":
       [ "boot.tzbeta.net", "dubnodes.tzbeta.net:9732",
         "franodes.tzbeta.net:9732", "sinnodes.tzbeta.net:9732",
         "nrtnodes.tzbeta.net:9732", "pdxnodes.tzbeta.net:9732",
         "dubnodes.tzbeta.net:9732", "franodes.tzbeta.net:9732",
         "sinnodes.tzbeta.net:9732", "nrtnodes.tzbeta.net:9732",
         "pdxnodes.tzbeta.net:9732", "dubnodes.tzbeta.net:9732",
         "franodes.tzbeta.net:9732", "sinnodes.tzbeta.net:9732",
         "nrtnodes.tzbeta.net:9732", "pdxnodes.tzbeta.net:9732" ],
     "listen-addr": "[::]:9732", "private-mode": false,
     "limits":
       { "connection-timeout": 10, "min-connections": 250,
         "expected-connections": 500, "max-connections": 800,
         "max_known_points": [ 5000, 3000 ],
         "max_known_peer_ids": [ 5000, 3000 ] } },
 "shell": { "chain_validator": { "bootstrap_threshold": 2 } } }
```

And this is what my node outputs when I miss a block:

```
Apr 24 16:08:40 - client.baking: No slot found at level 409407 (max_priority = 64)
Apr 24 16:10:17 - client.baking: No slot found at level 409408 (max_priority = 64)
Apr 24 16:11:14 - client.baking: New baking slot found (level 409409, priority 0) at 2019-04-24T16:11:08Z for ledger_tezos after BM6BjobPuFC3.
Apr 24 16:11:14 - client.baking: Waiting until 2019-04-24T16:11:45Z (31s) for more endorsements in the mempool (0/32 arrived).
Apr 24 16:11:25 - client.baking: Injected block BLLcqeashc4z for ledger_tezos after BM6BjobPuFC3 (level 409409, priority 0, fitness 00::0000000000c2f96a, operations 18+0+0+0).
Apr 24 16:13:35 - client.baking: No slot found at level 409410 (max_priority = 64)
```

Comment: You might want to lower your number of connections to 50 or 100.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to keep your tezos node/baker daemon updated.  The recent upgrade to 8.1 is very stable